# Cargar select dependientes en Dropdown en actualizacion con Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Buen dia, resulta que yo deseo una pagina de actualizacion de datos en el cual  se me carguen los select dependientes con jQuery and Ajax (lo cual ya lo tengo preconfigurado en otra pagina donde lo realizo como nuevo registro ~ y la informacion se carga de la db).

Comparto la vista de la pagina donde agrego la informacion nueva:

```
<div class="form-group"><!-- desplegar paises -->
                                              <label for="pais">* Pais</label>
                                              <select class="form-control select2" name="pais" id="country">
                                                  <option value="">Seleccionar pais</option>
                                                  <?php if(!empty($countries)){ foreach($countries as $row){ echo '<option value="'.$row['id_pais'].'">'.$row['nombre_pais'].'</option>';} }else{echo '<option value="">Pais no disponible</option>';}
                                                  ?>
                                              </select>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group"><!-- desplegar estados -->
                                              <label for="estado">* Departamento</label>
                                              <select class="form-control select2" name="estado" id="state">
                                                  <option value="">Seleccione pais primero</option>
                                              </select>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group"><!-- desplegar ciudades -->
                                              <label for="municipio">Municipio</label>
                                              <select class="form-control select2" name="municipio" id="city">
                                                  <option value="">Seleccione estado primero</option>
                                              </select>
                                          </div>
```

Cuando deseo actualizar la informacion en la pagina de actualizacion de datos me tengo este codigo, el cual agrego en el value del input:

```
<?php echo !empty($post['nombre_primero'])?$post['nombre_primero']:''; ?>
```

Con ello no tengo ningun problema.

Pero no puedo formular para cargar los selects dependientes y no dependientes de la misma manera que lo hago con los input al momento de actualizar la informacion.

Envio captura para ver el resultado hasta este momento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Edwin, sin el código del AJAX y el Jquery es difícil ayudarte, pero los `selects` no funcionan de la misma forma que los `inputs`. Un `select` tiene elementos `option` dentro para cada opción y la opción seleccionada se marca con `selected`.

Acá te dejo un ejemplo de la estructura para que puedas repensar el jQuery o compartirlo para que podamos darte una solución mejor.

```
<select>
  <option>Monday</option>
  <option>Tuesday</option>
  <option>Wednesday</option>
  <option>Thursday</option>
  <option selected>Friday</option>
  <option>Saturday</option>
  <option>Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ok veamos, yo entiendo ese punto, pero lo que no logro hacer, es que en una sección de actualización de datos, me cargue la opción que inicialmente había guardado en el select.

Comment: Eso deberías guardalos en la $_SESSION si recargas la página cada vez que cambia. Una forma más correcta sería enviar la info por ajax y procesar la respuesta sin tener que recargar la página.